# how to display text on an image in xaml (windows phone)

Tags: image, xaml, text, windows-phone

I have taken two controls image and textBlock, placed the textBlock on an image, but its text is not visible (the image comes up). Please help me on his guiding how this can be implemented. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Depending on which container you've put your controls in:

- If you've put them in a `Grid`, invert their order
- If you've put them in a `Canvas`, use the `Canvas.ZIndex` property to define which control should be displayed on top

Comment: Just to complete the answer, comment that it can also be done by clicking on the element with the right button of the mouse and selecting `Order->Bring to front`